# Getting the user id and user password through Docusign REST API?

Tags: docusignapi

Can we get the user email id and user password based on group details using DocuSign REST API calls?

Can we get the user password based on DocuSign user id or DocuSign email id using DocuSign REST API calls?

Answer (score 3):

You will **NOT** be able to retrieve User passwords through the DocuSign Api.

If such a feature exists then I would consider it a serious security flaw in the system.